# c++ two digit hexadecimal to decimal converter

Tags: c++, hex, data-conversion

I am trying to write a program that will allow a user to enter a two digit hexadecimal number and have it converted to an integer.  The only problem is that I am unable to have a user enter a char value into the program. Here is my code as it stands now.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
int val1, val2;
int decval;

cout << "Enter the first hex value: ";
cin >> val1;
cout << "Enter the second hex value: ";
cin >> val2;

if (val1 >=65 && val1 <=70)
{
val1 = (val1-55)*16;
    if (val2 >= 65 && val2 <= 70)
    {
        val2 -= 55;
        decval = val1+val2;
        cout << decval;
    }
    else if (val2 >= 0 && val2 <=9)
    {
        val2 = val2;
        decval = val1 + val2;
        cout << decval;
    }
    else
       cout << "Error";
}
else if (val1 >= 0 && val1 <=9)
{
    val1 = val1*16;
    if (val2 >= 65 && val2 <= 70)
    {
        val2 -= 55;
        decval = val1+val2;
        cout << decval;
    }
    else if (val2 >= 0 && val2 <=9)
    {
        decval = val1 + val2;
        cout << decval;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Error";
}
```

Comment: Check [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex) please.

Comment: Is the problem that you are asking users to type a *letter*, while your program asks for an *integer*?

Comment: Thats part of the issue. I need the program to be able to convert a hex that contains both letters and integers. @Jongware

Comment: @cbamford Take your time to read the link I was giving you.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  It have it working now by using the istringstream function. Thank you very much!

Comment: Feel free to post your own solution as a proper answer!